# How to get the Columns from a WebMatrix Query?

Tags: c#, webmatrix

The title is pretty self-explanitory, and it seems like it should be an easy task, but everything I've tried has not worked:

Here's my code, which works fine, but the table is variable, so I need to know the Columns it comes back with:

```
var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM " + Table);
```

Here's a list of techniques I've tried:

```
data.GetType().GetProperties().ToList(); 
// prints 'Int32 Count' and 'System.Object Item [Int32]'

data.GetDynamicMemberNames()
// Error: '...IEnumerable<dynamic> does not have a definition for GetDynamicMemberNames'
// I also tried using System.Linq and System.Dynamic

I could also iterate through a loop, but there's got to be a more elegant way, right?
```

I'd like to end up with a `List<String>` of the Column Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<String> cols = data.First().Columns;`

---

It turns out the [Columns Propery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord.columns%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is an `IList<string>` type.

However, it is a property of an individual row of the data result (a row is a DynamicRecord data type), so it is unfortunately inaccessible from the result Object (`data` in my example). To access it, you need to get a single row, and `.First()` seems to be a pretty easy way to do that.

Here's my whole code in case anyone needs it:

```
WebMatrix.Data.Database db = new WebMatrix.Data.Database();
db.Open("ConnectionString");
var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM " + Table);
List<String> cols = data.First().Columns;
```